# Why does the whole page refresh when I use jQuery to increase or decrease the font size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML page where I want one button to increase the font size and the same button to decrease the font size when clicked.

I am using jQuery like so:

```
$("p").css("font-size","20")
```

However, when I do that the font size increases for maybe 2 seconds and then goes back to normal. It appears that the page is refreshing after I click the button... Why is that?

Comment: Where's the click handler? It could be that you need to return false from it. If you are using ASP.Net for example, this is necessary for the page not to post back.

Comment: Can you provide the full jQuery code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return false [prevent the default action] so that the page won't be posted back.

Also my suggestion would be to use two different css classes for this and toggle those classes using

[toggleClass( class )](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll need a unit on the `font-size` value.

Second, could anything else trigger the reload (given it's not just the lack of units)?

Answer (score 1):

put `return false` at the end of the callback to prevent the link (button) from refreshing.

```
$('#fontBtn').click(function () {
    $("p").css("font-size","20px")
    return false;
});
```